# error TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 2. State, React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, typescript-typings

I am working on a InfiniteScroll with React and TypeScript.
When I am setting Posts state using setPosts and setting there a page using setPage I have an error **Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.** How can I declare in state that I am going to use two parameters and one of them is a setPage?

```
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [page, setPage] = useState();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const lastItemRef = useRef(null);
  const observer = useRef<IntersectionObserver>();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPosts().then((res: any) => {
      setPosts([...res.posts], setPage(res.page));
    });
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a single object with two properties like below to setPosts

```
setPosts({ posts: [...res.posts], page: res.page});
```

Alternatively, you need to set Posts and Page separately.

```
setPosts([...res.posts]);
setPage(res.page);
```

Answer (score 0):

setPosts() can have only one arguments.
if you want save both posts and page.
your code should be looks like this

```
setPosts([...posts, res.posts])
setPage(res.page) or setPage([...page, res.page])
```

I am not sure why you are using page hook, but I think this will be better to manage posts.

```
setPosts([...posts, {post: res.posts, page: res.page}])
```

or

```
setPosts([...posts, res])
```

and use `posts.posts`, and `posts.page`